# Position: absolute - высота равная высоте экрана за вычетом позиции родителя

Tags: javascript, html, css

Верстка:

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <button>
    <div class="container">
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Стили:

```
nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}
body.fix-nav nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 32px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #000;
}
```

**nav** - обычный блок навигации. Когда прокрутка страницы доходит до него, через javascript элементу `body` добавляется класс `fix-nav`. И, соответственно, `nav` закрепляется вверху экрана.

**button** - кнопка открытия/закрытия меню

**.container** - контейнер для меню, прикреплено к `nav`-у.

**ul** - само меню

Когда `nav` закреплен сверху экрана, меню там же. А когда прокрутка еще не дошла до навигации, меню закреплено относительно позиции `nav`-а.

Проблема в том, что мне нужно реализовать вертикальную прокрутку меню. А для этого мне нужно сделать элемент `.container` по высоте равный высоте экрана минус позиция `nav`-а (чтобы ничего не выходило за края экрана) - когда `nav` не закреплен.

Я пробовал использовать position: fixed для `.container`, но выходит криво. Особенно потому, что `nav` может быть как relative, так и fixed.
Можно было бы реализовать это на JavaScript, но, мне кажется, это будет нерационально с точки зрения производительности.

Answer (score 2):

Для решения вашего вопроса следует использовать calc() и единицу измерения vh. Итак, 100vh - это константа, которая всегда равна высоте окна браузера. Допустим, что высота nav равна 100px, тогда решением будет таким:

```
.container {
   height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

P.S. Есть кстати другой вариант. Если у .container родитель занимает всю высоту экрана, то можно растянуть наш блок с меню по его высоте с учетом занимаемого пространства nav:

```
.container {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px; /* Высота блока nav */
   bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: А почему нельзя использовать вместо `vh` `%` ?

Comment: @Yuri потому что нужно знать основы:
http://front-end.su/2015/10/07/viewport-units-vs-percent/

Comment: Хорошо тогда. +1 я уже поставил )

Comment: @Yuri хотя согласен, что если родитель занимает всю высоту экрана, то можно использовать 100%. Но здесь мы видим грубый пример и не знаем точно, какая высота будет на живом проекте и возможно ли будет вообще там применять родительским блокам height: 100%.